# Visual Studio Code Extension Install/Update Error: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"

Tags: visual-studio-code

Why can't I download or update any extensions from VS Code 1.54.3 on Windows 10 1930?

Every time I tried to update or install those extensions, it always shows this error in the Dev Tools:

[image: log]

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
>
> ERR [uncaught exception in sharedProcess]: XHR failed: downloading: XHR failed at

It says "XHR failed" and I can't find the fix for this issue.

Comment: It looks like VSCode cant connect to the download server, did you try disabling your firewall and check if it works? It could be that you block a download host? Here is a list of common hosts used by Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network

Comment: does it work if you download the extension from the marketplace and install it from the Extension bar top menu

Comment: Solved, i disabled my firewall and it works, thanks @Daantje

Comment: @BrandonIvander please add your comment as an **Answer** below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved in the comments:

[Daantje](/users/536590):

> It looks like VSCode cant connect to the download server, did you try disabling your firewall and check if it works? It could be that you block a download host? Here is a list of common hosts used by Code: [code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network)

[Brandon Ivander](/users/15513319):

> Solved, i disabled my firewall and it works, thanks @Daantje